# ASP.NET Core build on different platforms

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I created a simple ASP.NET Core application and I want to build it on Windows 10 for Windows 10 and CentOS 7. So my I have this in my project.json file:

```
"runtimes": {
    "win10-x64": { },
    "centos.7-x64": { },
    "win81-x64":  { }
  },
```

Without "win81-x64" I got an error:

> Can not find runtime target for framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0' compatible with one of the target runtimes: 'win81-x64, win8-x64, win7-x64'

After `dotnet build` command i see this:

> Project ListService (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0) will be compiled because expected outputs are missing Compiling ListService for .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0
>
> Compilation succeeded.
>       0 Warning(s)
>       0 Error(s)
>
> Time elapsed 00:00:14.3853704

And command `dotnet --info` shows:

> Product Information:
>    Version:            1.0.0-preview2-003131
>    Commit SHA-1 hash:  635cf40e58
>
> Runtime Environment:
>    OS Name:     Windows
>    OS Version:  6.3.9600
>    OS Platform: Windows
>    RID:         win81-x64

Am I missing something? Also the `dotnet publish -r foo-version` did not helped.

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.0.1"
    },
    "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0"
  },

  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
  },

  "runtimes": {
    "win10-x64": { },
    "centos.7-x64": { },
    "win81-x64":  { }
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "runtimeOptions": {
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "**/*.cshtml",
      "appsettings.json",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you try use "win10-x64": { }?

Comment: Yes, as you can see "win10-x64" is in my project.json file

Comment: Ohh yes yes , sorry. Put all project.json

Comment: Ok, I edited the question :)

Comment: Try edit "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.0.1"
    }  to    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.0.1","type": "platform"
    }

Comment: Does not work in my case. The build command seems to work but the folder centos.7-x64 does not appear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so now it works.
What I did was:

1. I removed `"type":"platform"` from `project.json` file
2. I ran command `dotnet build -r centos.7-x64` in cmd from project folder

And now i see

[image]